# unchecking remove splash screen causes an error

Tags: android, firemonkey, splash-screen

In building an Android app I wanted to remove the use of the splash screen. When I "uncheck" the include splash screen checkbox (Project Options - Icons). The application no longer deploys properly when I select "run". If I turn the checkbox back on and select run, the application deploys correctly and executes on the phone. I am running the latest version (11 with the November patch). Thank you for any help

Comment: The theory will not help in understanding your issue. :)

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear. I am using Delphi Rad Studio V11 to build a Firemonkey Android application. I wanted to remove the use of the Splash Screen, but when I uncheck the checkbox, the application gets an error when I try to run it. The specific error is Error: E2312 C:\Users\John\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\PhoneAct\Android\Debug\PhoneAct\res\values-v21\styles.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@drawable/splash_image_def'). Since I "uncheck" the box, I wouldn't expect it to try to deploy it.